# extending line in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

i am using this code to extedn lines in matplotlib and it is working fine but i want to know is there any faster way to do this ?

```
A=[106,125]
B=[135.06,135.3]

def find_next_point_by_slope_and_1_point (slope , px , py , distance):
    for i in range(0,distance):
        px = px + 1
        py = py + slope     
    return np.round(px,3) , np.round(py,3) 

slope ,intercept = np.polyfit([A[0],A[1]],[B[0],B[1]],1)
nextt = find_next_point_by_slope_and_1_point(slope,A[1],B[1],50)

x=[A[0],A[1]]
y=[B[0],B[1]]
plt.plot(x,y,color='red') # original line

x=[A[1],nextt[0]]
y=[B[1],nextt[1]]
plt.plot(x,y,linewidth=3) # extended
```

Comment: In the newest matplotlib there is a function [`axline()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axline.html) that extends a line to fill the plot. The line can be given either by two points or by a point and a slope.

Comment: yes , but i need coordinates of extended line which axline cannot provide as it is infinite line

Comment: It seems you simply want to measure the distance in the x direction. So `nextt[0] = B[0] + 50` and  `nextt[1] = B[1] + 50 * (B[1] - A[1]) / (B[0] - A[0])` might work.